# getAttribute method is not calling laravel using query builder

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8, accessor

I have tried multiple ways to call below method in the model

```
public function getFullNameAttribute()
    {
        return "{$this->first_name} {$this->last_name}";
    }
```

What I tried:

```
User::select('first_name', 'last_name')
        ->with([
            'fullName' => function($query){
                $query->select(DB::raw("CONCAT(first_name, ' ', last_name) AS full_name"));
            }
        ])
        ->where('user_id', $id)
        ->where('is_deleted', 0)
        ->first();
```

Another way I tried:

```
User::select(DB::raw("CONCAT(first_name, ' ', last_name) AS full_name"))
        ->with([
            'fullName' => function($query){
                $query->select('firstname', 'lastname');
            }
        ])
        ->where('user_id', $id)
        ->where('is_deleted', 0)
        ->first();
```

But nothing is calling `get<>Attribute` name.

Comment: Why the mixture of underscores? `firstname` and `first_name` - which is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define method in in your model

```
public function getFullNameAttribute()
    {
        return "{$this->first_name} {$this->last_name}";
    }
```

Then in query  for example if you are fetching one record then

```
 $res= \App\Models\User::first();

   dd($res->fullName);
```

It means you are attribute is `FullName` then first letter become `small letter` while accessing

Answer (score 2):

An accessor is not a relation. Try

```
$user = User::where('user_id', $id)->first();


dd($user->full_name);
```

Answer (score 2):

These are magic methods in Laravel.
That means that these are treated in the following way:

1. `getFullNameAttribute` is stripped of `get` and `attribute`; leaving just `FullName`.
2. This will then be converted into `snake_case`, resulting in `full_name`.
3. This value is then added to an `attributes` array, which is accessible in the view, like a regular property.

Effectively, this will leave you with the following code.

```php
$user = User::first();
echo $user->full_name;
```

This assumes you went with the first approach of:

```php
public function getFullNameAttribute()
{
    return $this->first_name . ' ' . $this->last_name;
}
```

---

If you would like to access the property as `$user->fullname`, then you'd need to go for the following approach:

```php
public function getFullnameAttribute()
{
    return $this->first_name . ' ' . $this->last_name;
}
```

Notice that we now have `Fullname`, with a lowercase `n`.
This is the case with all magic getters (and setters), they will be converted into `snake_case`, based on their `PascalCase`.

Interestingly, you could do the following and it would work:

```php
getfull_nameAttribute()
{
    // ...
}
```

[Relevant framework code](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/6383cc852f81bc9634919c0b38ab696eea48c351/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Concerns/HasAttributes.php#L513).
All Laravel cares about is the `get` and `Attribute` bookends.

Answer (score 1):

That's not, how [accessors](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-mutators#defining-an-accessor) work. You're treating it as a relation by using `with()`. Just remove the `with()` from your query and after querying the user, you can just access `$user->full_name;`

Answer (score 1):

when you try

```php
public function getFullNameAttribute()
{
   return "{$this->first_name} {$this->last_name}";
}
```

then inside model you need to add this as well

```php
protected $appends = ['full_name'];
```

this you were missing then it will work
ref link https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-mutators#defining-an-accessor

Comment: You only need to do the `$appends` part if you're going to [serialize](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-serialization) the model.